# Extracting all named values from an ansible array

Tags: list, variables, ansible

I'm not even quite sure how to describe what I'm trying to do!
So I'll just jump straight in.
I have a hosts file :

```
[jvbservers]
jvb0  ansible_host=serverA
jvb1  ansible_host=serverB
```

etc...

And I want a list of the servers in the jvbservers group. What I've come up with so far feels a bit OTT.

```
  set_fact:
    jvb_names: "{{ jvb_names|default([]) + [ hostvars[groups.jvbservers[item|int]].ansible_host ] }}"
  with_sequence: start=0 end="{{groups.jvbservers|length-1}}"
```

Gives me a result like I want :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "jvb_names": [
        "serverA", 
        "serverB"
    ]
}
```

Is this sensible? It feels like there should be a neater way to do something like :

```
hostvars[groups.jvbservers[*]].ansible_host
```

(Where "*" would be a pattern matching all valid options. Obvs that particular syntax doesn't exist!)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check [extract](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) filter:

```
{{ groups['jvbservers'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') | list }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?:

```
- name: show all the hosts matching jvbservers
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all: jvbservers
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/lookup/inventory_hostnames.html

Comment: inventory name and `ansible_host` are two different things.

Comment: It is exactly this problem. The inventory name or even ansible_host is not necessarily the actual hostname. With split horizon DNS and local host files etc.. it's hard to find a "correct" value for it. 
The example is a bit contrived but in reality, I'll need to get the FQDN from the setup vars, rather than the hosts list on the ansible box.